# pear XML_Serializer - eliminate superfluous tags

Tags: php, xml, xml-serialization

I create an array, then push 0..n elements onto one of the subarrays within the array
(easiest to see what I mean in the code below)

When I run the array through XML_Serializer, it adds extra tags around the pushed elements

```
$serializer_options = array(
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT => '    ',
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_RETURN_RESULT => TRUE,
    rootName => 'JZ_2103'
);
$serializer = &new XML_Serializer($serializer_options);

$otXmlArr = array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'reason' => 'null',
    'payload' => array(
        'ContactsResponse' => array()
    )
);

foreach ($mydata as $item) {
    array_push($otXmlArr['payload']['ContactsResponse'],
        array(
            'Contact' => array(
                'ID' => $item['id'],
                'FirstName' => $item['fname']
            )
        )
    );
}

$otXml = $serializer->serialize($otXmlArr);
```

**The xml that is created has extra tags `<XML_Serializer_Tag>`.  How do I eliminate these tags?**

```
<JZ_2103>
    <status>success</status>
    <reason>null</reason>
    <payload>
        <ContactsResponse>
            <XML_Serializer_Tag>
                <Contact>
                    <ID>10</ID>
                    <FirstName>Roy</FirstName>
                </Contact>
            </XML_Serializer_Tag>
        </ContactsResponse>
    </payload>
</JZ_2103>
```

**Abstr's solution almost works - it yields:**

From print_r of the array:

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [reason] => null
    [payload] => Array
        (
            [ContactsResponse] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Contact] => Array
                                (
                                    [ID] => 3
                                    [FirstName] => Joe
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Contact] => Array
                                (
                                    [ID] => 4
                                    [FirstName] => Fred
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Serialized XML:

```
<JZ_2103>
    <status>success</status>
    <reason>null</reason>
    <payload>
        <ContactsResponse>
            <Contact>
                <ID>3</ID>
                <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
            </Contact>
        </ContactsResponse>
        <ContactsResponse>
            <Contact>
                <ID>4</ID>
                <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
            </Contact>
        </ContactsResponse>
    </payload>
</JZ_2103>
```

Using Daniel's suggestion, the XML output is: 
Extra level of nesting :-(

```
<JZ_2103>
    <status>success</status>
    <reason>null</reason>
    <payload>
        <ContactsResponse>
            <Contact>
                <Contact>
                    <ID>3</ID>
                    <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
                </Contact>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <Contact>
                    <ID>4</ID>
                    <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
                </Contact>
            </Contact>
        </ContactsResponse>
    </payload>
</JZ_2103>
```

I'm going to give up on using serializer and just build the xml directly using simpleXml I think.  This all started as an attempt to save some time and, clearly, it hasn't!

Thanks to Daniel and Abstr for their help, even if it didn't quite get me to the finish line.

Comment: Close, so close:  See detail

Comment: Hi RoyHB. Did you try my solution? I realize you have switched to something else but I believe the answer was actually a lot more simple than others were suggesting...

Comment: I looked at your solution KHMKShore but it wouldn't have worked.  The system I send the XML to requires that the contact elements be named "Contact", not "Contact_1, etc

Answer (score 3):

Adding `'mode' => 'simplexml'` to $serializer_options should to it:

```
$serializer_options = array(
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT => '    ',
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_RETURN_RESULT => TRUE,
    'rootName' => 'JZ_2103',
    'mode' => 'simplexml', 
);
```

Or using constants,

```
$serializer_options = array(
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT => '    ',
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_RETURN_RESULT => TRUE,
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_ROOT_NAME => 'JZ_2103',
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_MODE => XML_SERIALIZER_MODE_SIMPLEXML,
);
```

Found it [here](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/docs/0.20.2/__filesource/fsource_XML_Serializer__XML_Serializer-0.20.2XMLSerializer.php.html#a428) on line 515.

> // use XML_SERIALIZER_MODE_SIMPLEXML to use parent name as tagname
>
> // if transforming an indexed array
>
> ```
> XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_MODE => XML_SERIALIZER_MODE_DEFAULT,
> ```

**EDIT**: updated to point to actual XML_Serializer codebase.

Changes should be made to the code as follows (thanks to @danielpsc, see comments):

```
$otXmlArr = array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'reason' => 'null',
    'payload' => array(
        'ContactsResponse' => array(
            'Contact' => array()
        )
    )
);

foreach ($mydata as $item) {
    array_push($otXmlArr['payload']['ContactsResponse']['Contact'],
        array(
            'ID' => $item['id'],
            'FirstName' => $item['fname']
        )
    );
}
```

**EDIT2**: Made changes to code

Comment: Close, so very close - see additional info at end of original post

Comment: Just tweak the `foreach` part so the un-named array is under `Contact` rather than `ContactsResponse` and you should (finally!) be there. This isn't going to format very well, but this works in my test case: `foreach ($mydata as $key => $item) {
    $otXmlArr['payload']['ContactsResponse']['Contact'][] = array(
           'ID' => $item['id'],
           'FirstName' => $item['fname']
      );
}`

Comment: Thanks again Daniel - I've added the result of your suggestion above.  I'd use it except that the organization that receives the XML will bounce it.  I'm going to abandon serializer I think and just build the xml directly

Comment: Updated the answer, but I'll admit I didn't try it out myself, hope it works :) @danielpsc's code shouldn't produce two levels of `Contact` as he moved it from the second array over to the first array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$serializer_options = array(
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT => '    ',
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_RETURN_RESULT => TRUE,
    rootName => 'JZ_2103'
);
$serializer = &new XML_Serializer($serializer_options);

$otXmlArr = array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'reason' => 'null',
    'payload' => array(
        'ContactsResponse' => array()
    )
);

foreach ($mydata as $key => $item) {
    $otXmlArr['payload']['ContactsResponse']['contact_'.$key] = array(
          'ID' => $item['id'],
          'FirstName' => $item['fname']
      );
}

$otXml = $serializer->serialize($otXmlArr);
```

Expected Result:

```
<JZ_2103>
    <status>success</status>
    <reason>null</reason>
    <payload>
        <ContactsResponse>
            <Contact_1>
                <ID>3</ID>
                <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
            </Contact>
            <Contact_2>
                <ID>4</ID>
                <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
            </Contact>
        </ContactsResponse>
    </payload>
</JZ_2103>
```

Please let me know if this is not the result...

Comment: With this approach you've just "moved" the problem now haven't you? We'll now have tags `Contact_1`, `Contact_2` etc., rather than multiple entries under `Contact`.

Comment: Either way he needs to have a layer to represent each individual object uniquely so that each ID is properly associated with its firstname. If he goes with your solution how will it parse when every key in the array is called "contact"?

I still don't understand how my answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: For the PHP you're right in that the array keys have to be unique. But in the XML the tags are effectively types. So both Joe and Fred in your example need to be tagged as just `Contact` or else the system reading in the XML won't identify them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your ContactResponses are all in a numerically-indexed array and XML doesn't allow a numeric tag. If you `print_r` the array you'll see:

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [reason] => null
    [payload] => Array
        (
            [ContactsResponse] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array  <---- ** The Problem **
                        (
                            [Contact] => Array
                                (
                                    [ID] => 1
                                    [FirstName] => daniel
                                )

                        ) ... etc ...
```

So XML_Serializer needs to give those numeric tags a valid value - by default it chooses to use `XML_Serializer_Tag`.

You can choose what name XML_Serializer uses for the anonymous tags with the "defaultTagName" option, so you can do this to get the result you need:

```
$serializer_options = array(
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT => '    ',
    XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_RETURN_RESULT => TRUE,
    'defaultTagName'=>'Contact',
    'rootName' => 'JZ_2103'
);
$serializer = &new XML_Serializer($serializer_options);

$otXmlArr = array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'reason' => 'null',
    'payload' => array(
        'ContactsResponse' => array()
    )
);

foreach ($mydata as $item) {
    array_push($otXmlArr['payload']['ContactsResponse'],
        array(
            'ID' => $item['id'],
            'FirstName' => $item['fname']
        )
    );
}

$otXml = $serializer->serialize($otXmlArr);
```

So here I've set the default tag name to Contact and removed the "Contact" label within the foreach loop - which makes that the tag that gets the defaultTagName.

**EDIT** Edited to try and make the explanation a bit clearer!

Comment: Thanks for your suggested work-around Daniel.  It looks like it would work for this specific case.  If a more general answer doesn't appear by the time the bounty expires I'll accept yours.

Answer (score -2):

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

        XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();

        xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml("C:\\path.xml");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Sample");

        ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;

        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Sample";

    }
```